# Tool to simulate sensor data

Tags: simulation, matlab, simulink

Say I have a light source at a distance of 1Km from a  light detector (photo detector). Right in front of the sensor, I keep a rotating reticle with some sort of pattern.

To better appreciate the situation take a look at the image below.

[image: https://www.ausairpower.net/XIMG/reticle-abc.png]

Now I want to simulate the detector output signal for various patterns on the reticle. For example "reticle B" from the above image would produce a square wave, and the "reticle A" would produce a  pulse train.

Is there any tool for doing such kind of simulation? Is there any python/matlab library?

Comment: A signal generator?

Comment: You do realize that A and B are essentially the same, only more pulses per rotation in one.